# Should MVC Controller GET actions use parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm considering simplifying my MVC controller actions.

Any thoughts on whether all GET actions should acquire their values using the RouteData.Values instead of taking parameters?

Comment: Properly set up routes should include your parameters as part of the route. You can poke into `RouteData` for this information, but isn't it simpler (and clearer) to just catch these values in the controller method parameters?

Comment: I thought that there would be a benefit in reducing the interface duplication; once in the route and again in the action method.  To clarify, if, by virtue of the fact that control has reached an action means that it has satisfied the pre-condition specified in the route.  I can understand your point on clarity though, but am unsure as to whether this is simpler as there is more code to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use RoutaData.Values if you setup your routes correctly, the default model binder does this for you. Behold the default route from global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Default", 
   "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
   new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
            );
```

So you can create an action like this:

```
 public ActionResult SomeAction(int id) {
   // in case of url '/MyController/SomeAction/1' id == 1
 }
```

You don't need to use RoutaData.Values at all, you just need to setup your routes correctly.. Why on Earth would you want to use something like this: (?!)

```
 public ActionResult SomeAction() {
   int id;
   if(int.TryParse(RoutaData.Values["id"] + "", out id))
   {
     // ...
   }
 }
```

Other arguments against this "pattern":

- complicated unit testing of such
  controller classes / actions
- circumvention of the model binding phase
  (pointed out by Ryan)
- circumvention of the model validation phase

Comment: +1 for mentioning unit test complications. Also, if you're parsing these values yourself (and using magic strings in the process!) you remove the ability to use custom model binders.

Comment: thanks Ryan. And as a consequence you also loose the ability to validate your models!

Comment: This is all making a lot more sense - I really appreciate all your input - thanks.